# Covering x% of shapefile in another shapefile using QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, style

[image]

I have a shapefile of the British Isles and I want to evenly distribute another polygon shapefile over it in randomly spaced splodges with tree symbols, at a certain % of land cover.

How could this be done?

It's to show what it would look like if woodland covered 30%, 40%, 50%, x% of the land.

For example like the attached image. Just randomly shaped and randomly distributed splodges of woodland which covers a certain percentage of the green shapefile I drew. But I want to automate it so I don't have to draw the shapefile myself - just say x% woodland cover, and it spits out the appropriate result

Comment: Hi Verdant, and welcome to GIS SE! Unfortunately, your question is unclear: the trees should be a point layer? Then how can a point layer cover a certain area? points have 0 dimension. You also did not tell us how the woodland should be distributet over Great Britain: just randomly 30%, 40%, 50%, x% of the land? Please edit your initial post to clarify. Otherwise, it's impossible to help and the question risks to be closed. Please help avoiding this unpleasant situation. By the way: "Shapefile" in this context does not help much - rather say what type of geometry it is.

Comment: Hi, apologies I have amended the question - hopefully it is clearer now

Comment: A screenshot about how you imagine the output to look like would help.

Comment: Have attached image

Answer (score 1):

You can use pyqgis and buffer the layer with an increasingly smaller buffer distance, then find the best distance:

```py
lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Britain')[0] #Change
goal_percentage = 30 #Change

def givearea(geometryfeatures):
    "A function to calculate sum of all geometries in a list"
    return int(sum([f.area() for f in geometryfeatures])/1e6)

geoms = [f.geometry() for f in lyr.getFeatures()] #List all layer geometries
start_area = int(givearea(geoms)) #Find 
goal_area = int(givearea(geoms)*goal_percentage/100)
increment = -5000 #A smaller increment (like -2500) will give more accurate results but process more slowly

#Buffer the layer with smaller and smaller distances
buffer_results = [] #Store the results in this list, [area and distance]
for buffdist in range(-10000, -100000, increment): #You might need to adjust -10k and -100k
    print(buffdist)
    buffered_geometries = [geom.buffer(buffdist, 2) for geom in geoms]
    buffer_results.append([givearea(buffered_geometries), buffdist])
    
ideal_buffdist = min(buffer_results, key=lambda x: abs(goal_area-x[0]))[1] #Find the buffer with the smallest deviation from goal area
print('The best buffer distance is: ', ideal_buffdist)

#Buffer the layer
processing.runAndLoadResults("native:buffer", {'INPUT':lyr.source(),'DISTANCE':ideal_buffdist,
    'SEGMENTS':5,'END_CAP_STYLE':0,'JOIN_STYLE':0,'MITER_LIMIT':2,'DISSOLVE':False,
    'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
```

[image]